# for question about autorotation

Tags: iphone

my superview is UItabelview and my subviews are UITabelview and UIDatePicker.
for my subviews didn't able to call

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

why?
 bcoz this method calls when view rotates and at that time i want to set autoresizingmask method for that view so that when my subview rotates from Portrait to landscape mode it's view resizes automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your subview responds to

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
}
```